# How to add Item to ComboBox from UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Ok maybe i'm a little bit stupid but i can't find a way to Add an Item to my `Combobox` and get it as `SelectedItem`. So what do i miss?

### Current Code

**LoginV.XAML**

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="102,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="155"
          IsEditable="True" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Loginname"
          ItemsSource ="{Binding alleBenutzer}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding selectedBenutzer}"/>
```

**LoginVM.CS**

```
    public List<User> alleBenutzer{ get; set; }
    public User selectedBenutzer
    {
        get { return _selectedBenutzer; }
        set
        {
            _selectedBenutzer = value;

            if (selectedBenutzer != null)
            {
                //do stuff
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => benutzerEinrichtungen));
        }
    }
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Loginname { get; set; }
    }
```

### Summary

How can i provide following behavior?
User runes the App added the Word "Admin" in the `Combobox` Control which will result in an `SelectedItem != null` so that i can do `if(selectedBenutzer.Loginname =="Admin") DoStuff;`

Comment: Your question is tagged by `MVVM`. Why do you want to add item from UI, instead of adding it from you view model?

Comment: @Dennis ok Add is maybe the wrong word but i want a hidden user (Admin) who should not be in the list so the User has to add the word "Admin" in the Combobox to aktivate this user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after some further research it turns out that i need to bind to the `Text` Property which contains the Value i was looking for

here an simple example

**XAML**

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,23,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
              IsEditable="True"                  
              ItemsSource="{Binding mySimpleItems}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding mySimpleItem}"
              Text="{Binding myNewSimpleItem}"/>
```

**Code**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SimpleVM();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleVM
    {    
        private string _mySimpleItem;
        private string _myNewSimpleItem;
        private bool isNew = true;

        #region properties

        public ObservableCollection<string> mySimpleItems { get; set; }

        public string mySimpleItem
        {
            get { return _mySimpleItem; }
            set
            {
                _mySimpleItem = value;
                if (_mySimpleItem != null)
                {
                    isNew = false;
                    MessageBox.Show(_mySimpleItem);
                }
                else
                    isNew = true;
            }
        }

        public string myNewSimpleItem
        {
            get { return _myNewSimpleItem; }
            set
            {
                _myNewSimpleItem = value;

                //if SelectedItem == null
                if (isNew) 
                    if (_myNewSimpleItem == "Super")
                    {
                        mySimpleItem = _myNewSimpleItem;
                        mySimpleItems.Add(_myNewSimpleItem);                            
                    }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region cTor

        public SimpleVM()
        {
            var ObCol = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            ObCol.Add("Max");
            ObCol.Add("Dennis");
            ObCol.Add("Lucas");

            mySimpleItems = ObCol;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` for `alleBenutzer`:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _alleBenutzer;
public ObservableCollection<string> alleBenutzer
{
    get
    {
        return _alleBenutzer;
    }
    set
    {
        _alleBenutzer= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("alleBenutzer");
    }
}
```

1. Add a button `Add user`.
2. Add `AddUser()` method to your `ViewModel`:

   `public void AddUser()
    {
        alleBenutzer.Add(new User {...});
    }`
3. Assign a `RelayCommand` to `Click` event of the button.
4. Assign the same `RelayCommand` to `AddUser()` method of your `ViewModel`

Comment: ok show me an working example how you would do it from the UI ... , because that will only work from codebehind or Viewmodel AFAIK

Comment: ah sure i could do this, but it has to be in the Combox because it should be an Hidden User(Admin) so the inserted Loginname will be an Trigger

Comment: What do you mean `it has to be in the Combox` ? What is *it*?

Comment: sry for my English, i mean the insert/add of the new User has to go over the Combox Control. It's defined in our functional specification documen as an security "feature"

Comment: Then you have to use proper event of your `ComboBox` instead of `Click` event of the button

Comment: is there no way to get the String ? or mavbe i could write an converter but i don't know where i should place it in my XAML

Comment: If you want to call the setter, you have to write `SelectedItem="{Binding selectedBenutzer, Mode=TwoWay}"` . If the user leaves the combobox, the setter will be called and you can check there the value. You can also write a helper class, so you can check the input by the KeyDown-Event, but like i said, it's an extra class and not in the VM-class.

Comment: @Rudi `SelectedItem` is always null if you type some letters in the `ComboBox` that doesn't match any Item from your `ItemsSource`

Comment: @WiiMaxx `SelectedText` is not

Comment: @AndreyGordeev there is non `SelectedText`property in `ComboBox`

Comment: `            get
            {
                if (_selectedBenutzer == null)
                    _selectedBenutzer = new User();
                return _selectedBenutzer;
            }`

Comment: @Rudi please take a look on the Summary part of my question